# Why can't I margin the div, why do I have to margin the child to margin the div?

Tags: css, margin

This has 2 fixes...which is really weird to me.

1: If I remove the tag #MARGIN-30 and Remove the tag #Nav-bar under margin-3 it fixes itself when I reapply said tags.

2: If I add overflow:hidden;

The question is, is anyone able to assist me with the reason for this happening, like...I've never had this on any prior project or learning experience with css.

Comment: Just updated it and it fixed itself when I removed overflow:hidden;
Sorry but I don't know how to ever via codepen?

Comment: We are definitely going to need some code. There's a way to put code in stack snippets (one of the buttons in the top bar of the editor), this has more information: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I totally forgot to add the link, sorry about that

https://codepen.io/Salt_Salt/pen/oNZgJbN

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears as though you are falling victim to [Margin Collapse](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Box_Model/Mastering_margin_collapsing). It's just one of those many things that are a bit weird in HTML/CSS.

> The top and bottom margins of blocks are sometimes combined (collapsed) into a single margin whose size is the largest of the individual margins (or just one of them, if they are equal), a behavior known as margin collapsing. Note that the margins of floating and absolutely positioned elements never collapse.